# jquery - content to appear on ONE particular select option.

Tags: jquery, html-select

I am new here.
I am trying to learn jquery - and i have a problem that I can't fix. I think I am pretty close? but i've worked myself up into a muddle over it and now i cant see the wood for the trees.

I have a form with a select in it.  if the user selects the option 'YES' then i want another peice of content to appear.  if the user selects no, then they just carry on filling in the form. i do realise that perhaps this could have been done with radio buttons, but i am bound to the snippet of html i have and can't change it.

```
<form>
<select id="test-select">
  <option>select</option>
  <option>yes</option>
  <option>no</option>
</select>
<div class="show-me">
  <p>HOORAAAAYYYYYYYYYY!!!!!!!</p>
</div>
    <!--more form goes below this line here - not important to the question -->
</form>
```

so far, i have the jquery working that it can get the values of the options. but then i am stuck. 
in my head i realise i need to do something IF the value of the option equals YES but i have  no idea how to write that.  the piece below is not working at all for me.

```
$(function(){
$("#test-select").change(function(){
var selectedValue = $(this).find(":selected").val();
console.log("the value you selected: " + selectedValue);
    if $(selectedValue).contains('yes') {
        console.log("you have selected yes - so write something to show the div now");
    }
    else {
        console.log("you have not selected yes, carry on filling in form");
    }
});
});
```

can anyone explain the next step to me please, so i can understand jquery better and where i am slipping up

i have seen a post here where someone has content changing on each different select, but i only want my div to appear when YES has been selected so i couldn't translate that into how to fix my problem unfortuantely. i did try!

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First off I believe you just need to do

```
var selectedValue = $(this).val();
```

To get the selected item in a  list.  Then you just need to do something like ...

```
if (selectedValue == "yes") 
{ $(".show-me").show(); }
else 
{ $(".show-me").hide(); }
```

Edit: Here is a link to an example in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hR2sx/

Answer (score 1):

You're overthinking it!

```
if $(selectedValue).contains('yes') {
```

This line won't work, since calling $() against selectedValue will attempt to make it a jQuery object, whereas before it was a string.

You should try this instead:

```
if (selectedValue=="yes") {
```

Comment: argh! you are right, i was totally over thinking it. i was so stuck for hours on that line (lame i know, but i am just learning this) thank you sooo much for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

### [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/crCh7/2)

```
$('.show-me').hide();

$("#test-select").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

    if(val == 'yes'){
        $('.show-me').fadeIn();
    }
    else{
        $('.show-me').fadeOut();
        // do the rest........
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var selectedValue = $("#test-select option:selected").val();
if(selectedValue == "yes") { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the div is `display:none` by default:

```
$(function(){
    $('#test-select').change(function() {
        $('div.show-me').toggle('yes'==$(this).val());
    });
});
```